# UICollectionView/AppDelegate causing crashes while following video tutorial

Tags: swift, crash, appdelegate

After returning to Swift after a long time I really need a number pad for what I'm working on now. I'm currently following this video https://youtu.be/vI7m5RTYNng?t=319 (start at 5:19) however at 7:18 when he builds the app again and it works, mine still crashes with the same error. I've checked the code in AppDelegate at least 5 times and everything is exactly the same as his code down to the last character. I've attached my code below. I don't know if something has changed with Swift since the video was released since when I switched to AppDelegate for the first time `var window:UIWindow?` wasn't there, I had to type it in myself. I'm frustrated to say the least. Any help much appreciated.

My code for proofreading:

AppDelegate:

[image]

ViewController:

[image]

Error message:

```
2020-02-26 00:14:41.148993+0000 software[714:18581] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you assigned class`UICollectionViewController` to the vc in IB but it's a usual vc not a `UICollectionViewController` template

Comment: Yes, because I'm trying to create a collection view, and that's what it says to do in the video. So what do I now need to do that's different to what it says in the video?

Answer (score 0):

```
// in scene delegate

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
   //Solved Scene Code
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourControllerName(collectionViewLayout: layout))
    //        
}
```